# How To Pass A Static Token (Key) To API Endpoint?

Tags: javascript, ajax, token, endpoint, apigee

I'm working on a web app, which needs to send an ajax call to an Apigee API endpoint - and it needs to send an API key in order to execute the API call. How can I do this in a secure way?

Comment: You don't want the user to see the token? There's only one way to do this. Open an endpoint in your backend that makes that API call for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use multiple policies in APIGEE, try to make use of these javascript policy, Service Call out policy and extract variable and assign message policies

Refer these sites:

APIGEE docs: http://docs.apigee.com/
community: https://community.apigee.com/index.html